# How can I calculate time difference(HH:MM:SS) from date_time (ISO format) in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime-format

I have a table T1 in Postgres which is as follows:

```
| event | Date_Time                |
|-------|--------------------------|
| start | 2018-04-30T06:09:30.986Z |
| run   | 2018-04-30T10:37:38.044Z |
| end   | 2018-04-30T11:39:38.044Z |
```

The Date_Time is in ISO format (stored as varchar) and I need to calculate the difference in Date_Time so that my output is as follows:

```
| event | Date_Time                | Time_Difference |
|-------|--------------------------|-----------------|
| start | 2018-04-30T06:09:30.986Z | 4:28:08         |
| run   | 2018-04-30T10:37:38.044Z | 1:02:00         |
| end   | 2018-04-30T11:39:38.044Z |                 |
```

(10: 37: 38 - 06: 09: 30 = 4:28:08)

How can I do this using SQL?

Comment: Consider using a date time data type if the DBMS (BTW: yours is?) supports it. In a varchar all sorts of funny things can be stored. Are spaces allowed in ISO date format? I have doubts...

Comment: Please change the type of Date_Time column to dateTime,so that you can process it like a date and not just some plain string.

Comment: Since date and time functions vary between DBMSs, it would help if you would tag your question with the target DBMS.

Comment: I am using POSTGREsql. Spaces are not allowed in the date-time. The actual example is 2018-03-29T04:29:51.880Z. I would like to have 2 solutions : 1) If I change the data type as "datetime" 2) If I keep it as varchar

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : there are no spaces in my ISO date format. How do I proceed now?

Comment: I have removed spaces in my sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unrelated to the question, but: you should **never** store timestamp (or date or number) values in a `varchar`.

---

You first have to convert the varchar value to a timestamp. If the values are indeed formatted correctly, you can simply cast them: `Date_Time::timestamp` - or maybe to a `timestamptz`.

As far as I can tell, you want the different to the *next row* in your result. This can be achieved with the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `lead()`

```
select event, 
       Date_Time,
       date_time::timestamp - lead(date_time::timestamp) over (order by date_time::timestamp) as time_difference
from the_table
order by date_time;
```

The result of subtracting one timestamp from another is an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) you can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+format+interval)  if you want.